# Merge to New Raster resulting a raster with cell value 0 to 255

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arctoolbox, tools, mosaic

I am using the mosaic to new raster tool to mosaic two rasters together, one 2-bit and one 4-bit, and the output raster has given all the previously nodata pixels the value 3. Some of the pixels in the output should be 3, their original and intended value, while the majority should be nodata or a much higher or lower value like 255 or -/+ 32,768 that appears when I use the mosaic tool on data with different extents.

Any idea what could be causing this? Should I be converting the 2-bit data to 4-bit to match the other raster?

I have used the tool on very similar data for the exact same process and not had an issue like this before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, make the data 8 bit. I would use `GDAL_Translate -ot byte`, it's less messy than trying to do it in ESRI.

[Mosaic to new raster](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Mosaic_To_New_Raster/001700000098000000/) will also resample your data if there isn't an exact (or near exact) cell alignment. In the [mosaic tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Mosaic/001700000097000000/), which is called by [mosaic to new raster](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Mosaic_To_New_Raster/001700000098000000/)
there is a cell alignment parameter which determines if a raster is resampled or shifted. A value of 0.5 guarantees shifted cells, but this parameter is missing from the *to new raster* tool; to avoid resampling your classified data either get the cells to line up or use the straight *mosaic* tool - you need to [create a new raster](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000096000000) to put it into.

To get the cells to line up you can use [Shift](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000007t000000) with a snap raster of one of the other rasters.